# Overriding nested Helm values on the command line doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install [a Helm chart](https://github.com/munnerz/kube-plex/tree/master/charts/kube-plex) that has template sections like these

```yaml
{{- if not .Values.persistence.data.claimName }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
{{- if .Values.persistence.data.storageClass }}
  storageClassName: {{ .Values.persistence.data.storageClass | quote }}
{{- end }}
---
{{- end }}
```

Note the `.Values.persistence.data.storageClass`.

I have provided these values on the command line by piping this file into helm (with `-f -`):

```
$ cat /tmp/values.yaml
claimToken: claim-GscEQwRPBmXSsYBjwyUD
image.repository: linuxserver/plex
image.tag: arm64v8-latest
ingress.enabled: true
nodeSelector:
  beta.kubernetes.io/arch: arm64
persistence.config.storageClass: rook-cephfs
persistence.data.storageClass: rook-cephfs
persistence.transcode.storageClass: rook-cephfs
service.type: LoadBalancer
```

Passing them to Helm install on the command line doesn't seem to work and we end up with two different keys:

```
$ cat /tmp/values.yaml | helm upgrade --debug --dry-run -i kube-plex -f - ../kube-plex/charts/kube-plex/
COMPUTED VALUES:
...
persistence:
  ...
  data:
    accessMode: ReadWriteMany
    size: 40Gi
    storageClass: ""
  ...
...
persistence.data.storageClass: rook-cephfs
...
```

Note how `persistence.data.storageClass` appears both as a "flat" key and a nested dict. The nested dict value doesn't get overridden.

Passing `--set persistence.data.storageClass=rook-cephfs` as a command line flag does work.

How do I override nested values on the command line by providing a file?

Answer (score 1):

The Go `text/template` language uses `.` to mean field navigation: in an expression `.Values.persistence.data.storageClass` it starts at the special variable `.`, looks up the `Values` member of that, looks up the `persistence` member in that, and so on.  If you pass override values using a `helm install -f` option, your YAML file layout needs to match this:

```yaml
persistence:
  config:
    # not "persistence.config.storageClass"; follows the nested map layout
    storageClass: rook-cephfs
  data:
    storageClass: rook-cephfs
  transcode:
    storageClass: rook-cephfs
```